# Access a component method from another component in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a dashboard component, a head component, and a userOverview component.

dashboard component .ts file

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    startTour() {
      // do something
    }
}
```

userOverview component .ts file

```
export class UserOverviewComponent implements OnInit {
    startTour() {
      // do something else
    }
}
```

header component .html file

```
<button (click)="openTour()"></button>
```

header component .ts file

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    openTour() {
                   // In here, I want to ask is there any way I could make a 
                   // call to  different component with the same method same.

      this.name = componentName // The component Name, such as
                                // DashboardComponent, UserOverviewComponent

      this.name.startTour(); // Something like this
    }
}
```

Now I am able to get this.name when navigate to different component, but I know by using this.name.startTour() is definitely not going to work.

Thanks for any hints or solutions.

Comment: did the answer helpe?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thank you for the help, however your answer is not the one I am look for.

Comment: What did you look for then?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Thanks for the follow up, I actually solved the problem by extract the method to the shared folder. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **`cannot`** just call like that if the components are independent.If component1 and component2 are siblings you can use [**`EventEmitter`** **`@Input`**](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

You can use also use a Shared service with subject. A service in Angular is a singleton, meaning it is managed as a single instance. So if each of the components access the service, they will access the same shared data.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it is not a good idea to call a method from another component, I will try to put make a service instead. Cheers

Comment: Move the method to the shared folder solved the problem. Thanks